# UITableView Header文字などの明るさ挙動について

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

UITableView上にBackgroundColor = UIBlackのUIView(darkView)を重ね、そのViewのalphaを操作することでUITableViewの明るさのコントロールをしようとしています。
darkViewのalphaを上げて行くと一様に暗くなっていくのですが、TableViewの一部(Headerなどの文字やセパレート線など)が暗くならず、明るいままとなってしまいます(添付画像参照:"SETTING"という文字がdarkViewの影響を受けず、明るいまま)。
これらを一様に暗くする方法はありますでしょうか(この挙動はどのClassのどのPropertyによるものでしょうか)。また、この挙動を他のUILabelやUIButtonなどに応用することはできるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

以下、当該部分のコードを記載します。

UITableViewControllerはStoryBoardで実装しています。UISliderを`nightSlider`という名前でIB接続しています。
[image: SettingTableViewContoller]

```
@implementation SettingTableViewController
{
    UIView *nightView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    nightView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    nightView.frame = self.view.frame;
    nightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    nightView.alpha = 1.0f - _nightSlider.value;
    nightView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:nightView];
}

- (IBAction)nightSlider:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = sender;
    nightView.alpha = 1.0f - slider.value;
}
```

なお、当View(SettingView)後方のViewにも、同じようなdarkViewを設定し、同じ輝度調整ができるようになっております。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: UIViewを重ねている該当部分のソースなど関連する部分のソースがあったほうがよい質問のように感じます。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。当該部分のコードを掲載しました。